# injectors: CA and Fed types not interchangeable?

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-injectors, cobalt, compatibility, ecotec

'07 Cobalt, 2.2L Ecotec; CA emissions spec (RPO L61)

I inadvertently tried to install a Fed-emissions spec injector in our CA-emissions engine.  AFAICT, it would not seat properly in the intake manifold, which also prevented the other injectors from seating.  I replaced this with a CA-spec injector, which does fit.  So, all is well, mostly.

My question is, are these injectors actually incompatible?  I can see why California might want that, and the nozzle ends are noticeably different.  (pix below).  But, ... really?

I have to think I just did something wrong when I tried the Fed-spec injector.  Yes?  No?

[image: nozzle end]

Comment: I can't be for sure, but I'd suggest since CARB is expecting some type of "different" injector (I see parts specific to CA compliant and Federal compliant listed as you've suggested), they might force manufacturers to have a different fitment so you can't do what you inadvertently tried to do.